# Author name linked to his address

Tags: org-export

Is there a specific way to have the author email address linked on his name when exporting in LaTeX, or if I have to do it with `LaTeX` commands using `hyperref` package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#+author: [[http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/563/wvxvw][wvxvw]]
```

From looking at the source of `org-export-as`, you can do the same for `date`, `title`, but not `email` fields.

Comment: Nice. But to answer to my question, it should be something like `#+author: [[mailto:name@domain.com][Name]]`.